# How to focus arrow keys on ListView while writing in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a simple Windows Form containing a TextBox and a ListView.

I want to allow the user to write text into the TextBox while focusing on the ListView (typing text into the TextBox while controlling the ListView with the keyboard arrow keys).

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the keyboard events on the TextBox?

Answer (score 2):

Implement IMessageFilter for your Form and change the intended recipient when appropriate:

```
public partial class form1 : Form, IMessageFilter 
{

    private NativeWindow nw = null;

    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        nw = new NativeWindow();
        nw.AssignHandle(this.listView1.Handle);
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);

        // so you can see the selection moving when the arrow keys are pressed in the TextBox
        this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
        this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
    }

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.HWnd.Equals(this.textBox1.Handle))
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                case WM_KEYUP:
                    switch ((Keys)m.WParam)
                    {
                        case Keys.Up:
                        case Keys.Down:
                        case Keys.Right:
                        case Keys.Left:                               
                            m.HWnd = this.listView1.Handle; // change the handle to the ListView
                            nw.DefWndProc(ref m); // send the message to the ListView
                            return true; // suppress handling by the TextBox
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I use this method for a form triggered by a PPT VSTO addin button. It works only for the very first time when PPT launches and  the button clicked. But doesn't work afterwards. Any comment on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to trap?  The button click on the popup form?